# RxJava - retryWhen - propagate retry obervable error

Tags: java, rx-java

I am struggling to understand `retryWhen`.

My use case is the following:

- I have one main observable
- If an error occurs I want to execute a
  different observable (also having a different result) in between
- If this second observable is successful, I want to re-execute the original
  observable **once** (if an error occurs during the first retry I do not want an additional retry)
- If this second observable is not successful, I want to propagate
  the error to the subscriber of the main observable

How do I do this?

Thank you already!

---

**UPDATE**
What I tried so far:

```
public class RetryTest {

  private int i = 0;

  @Test
  public void testRetry() {
      Observable
              .create((Observable.OnSubscribe<String>) subscriber -> {
                  if (i == 0) {
                      i++;
                      throw new RuntimeException("Main error");
                  } else {
                      subscriber.onNext("Main success");
                      subscriber.onCompleted();
                  }
              })
              .retryWhen(observable -> {

                  // HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP, i need something like:

                  Observable.just("Error handling observable")
                          .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {

                              @Override
                              public void onCompleted() {
                                  // Do retry ONCE
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                  // Propagate error
                              }

                              @Override
                              public void onNext(String s) {
                                  // Nothing to do here
                              }
                          });
              })
              .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted() {
                      System.out.println("onCompleted");
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onError(Throwable e) {
                      System.out.println("onError: " + e);
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onNext(String s) {
                      System.out.println("onNext: " + s);
                  }
              });
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? (I mean please share a minimal example demonstrating that and describe the issues you're having with that)

Comment: Added an example of what I tried and where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simplier solution. In your case you don't need `retryWhen` operator, use `onErrorResumeNext` instead:

```
Observable mainObservable = Observable.just("Your main Observable");
Observable secondObservable = Observable.just("Your second Observable");

mainObservable
        .onErrorResumeNext(o1 -> secondObservable.flatMap(o2 -> mainObservable))
        .subscribe();
```

Here `onErrorResumeNext` intercepts an error and executes second Observable, then main Observable. If there will be an error
 - it will propagate downstream. All fits your criteria.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a method like `onErrorResumeNext` that has the original observable as parameter? I would like to externalize this in a separate class/method without the need to pass in the original observable.

Comment: You can use `compose()`